# Splitting comma separated string in R for every row

Tags: r

I have a table (named 'df') in R with 3000 rows.

In each row, in the column 'TestResults', there is a string of numbers separated by commas (e.g. 5, 10, 1, 3...).

I would like to create a new column in 'df' called 'TestValue1' which only includes the first number in the string found in 'TestResults' (therefore, in the example row, under 'TestResults' would be the value "5".

This is the code I am running :

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  rname=rownames(df)[i]
  a <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(df[rname, "TestResults"],",")))
  df[rname, "TestValue1"] <- a[1]
}
```

The error message I receive is :

`Error in strsplit(df[rname, ("TestResults"))],  : 
  non-character argument`

However, when I run : `class(df$TestResults)`, I receive :
`[1] "character"` so the string of numbers is a character

(This error holds true even in the absence of the as.numeric function being called)

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: It may be helpful if you provide a small bit of sample data to work with. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to know without any of your data—your error points to a data types issue but we can't see or test it. You also don't need to use a for-loop, since these types of operations are vectorized in R. Why not just use regex to extract the first set of numeric characters from the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gsub` function seems to work with the sample data I generated. Hopefully it will work on your data!

```
#Created example data
res<-data.frame((rbind(("5, 10, 1, 3"),("4,3,2,10"), ("8,21,0,8"))))
names(res)<-"TestResults"
res$TestResults<-(as.character(res$TestResults))

#Run gsub
res$TestValue1<-gsub(",.*", "\\1", res$TestResults)

#See results
res
```

Output results:

```
  TestResults TestValue1
1 5, 10, 1, 3          5
2    4,3,2,10          4
3    8,21,0,8          8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use `strsplit` you could do the following:

```
df <- cbind(df, TestValue1 = as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$TestResults, ","), `[[`, 1))))
```

**Output**

```
   TestResults TestValue1
1  5, 10, 1, 3          5
2 12, 0, 19, 7         12
3 13, 4, 5, 11         13
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  TestResults = c("5, 10, 1, 3", "12, 0, 19, 7", "13, 4, 5, 11"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```